# Calculations in matrix table

Tags: matrices, recreational-mathematics

I am facing a problem that I am unable to solve. I have a quiz with 21 questions divided into two parts, questions 1-13 and questions 14-21. There are five possible answers, with the first three not important so I assigned them a value of zero.

Now, however, I have three rules for calculating the final three options. In the program in which I have to do the quiz, I have general arithmetic operations available; addition, subtraction, division, multiplication and use of parentheses.

I need to put together a formula that would give me different ranges from which to assess which option belongs to the user who completed the quiz.
The rules are:

- OPTION 1 = if questions 1 - 13 have six or more answers with 3 or 4 and questions 14 - 21 if there are six or more answers with 3 or 4
- OPTION 2 = if questions 1 - 13 have six or more answers with 3 or 4 and questions 14 - 21 if there are less than six answers with 3 or 4
- OPTION 3 = if there are less than 5 answers in each set of questions with 3 or 4

It would be easiest if I could set ranges, for example:
0 - 10 = OPTION 1, 11 - 20 = OPTION 2 and 21 - 30 = OPTION 3
Thanks for any help!

|  | Answer 0 | Answer 1 | Answer 2 | Answer 3 | Answer 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Question 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 5 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 6 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 7 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 9 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 10 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 11 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 12 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 13 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 14 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 15 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 16 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 17 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 18 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 19 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 20 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |
| Question 21 | 0 | 0 | 0 | x | x |

Answers 0, 1 and 2 are not important so I placed 0 there.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/help!

Comment: I can't follow this at all.

Comment: Did I made mistake? It's not clear? :(

Comment: @SeanRoberson I edited message and I hope it’s better to understand now.

Comment: It is still incredibly difficult to follow. What do you mean, Option 1, Option 2, Option 3? Please spell out, using clear language, exactly what you want. I can't parse this.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Thanks for the response. I will try to explain as simply as possible. I have a questionnaire that identifies three diagnoses of children. The questionnaire contains 21 questions, and the diagnosis is made on the basis of answers between questions 1 - 13 and between questions 14 - 21. If in segment 1 to 13 there are six or more answers with 3 or 4 and in segment 14 - 21 if more as six or more answers with 3 or 4 then the child has Disease 1 (OPTION 1).

Comment: If there are six or more answers with 3 or 4 in the first set of questions and less than six with 3 or 4 in the second set, then it is disease 2 (OPTION 2). If there are less than 5 answers with 3 or 4 in each set of questions, the child has disease 3 (OPTION 3). I hope it is clearer now. I want to digitize the process of verifying these tests, as this could help more children.

Comment: @panigale are you allowed to multiply scores of different question? Also, is the division operation float division or integer division? Is there a modulo operation also present?

Comment: @AJ yes I'm allowed to multiply scores, yes.

Answer (score 0):

So you can possibly use two digits to store information of questions 1-13 and remaining digits to store information of questions 14-21. Here is how:
Assign +1 point for options 3 and 4 for all questions 1-13.
Assign +100 points for options 3 and 4 for all questions 14-21.
Let us assume that the score is $s$.
You can get the number of 3 or 4 answers from 14-21 by dividing $s$ by $100$. Assuming this is integer division. $m=\lfloor{s/100}\rfloor$
You can get the last two digits by $l=s-m$
Determine:
OPTION 1 if $l\geq 6$ and $m \geq 6$
OPTION 2 if $l\geq 6$ and $m < 6$
OPTION 3 if $l<5$ and $m<5$
Hope this helps!

Comment: Yeah I was thinkig of that too, but the problem is that I can not use if in the program where this quiz is made. I can only use ranges for options. Let's say, range between 100 - 200 is OPTION 1, range between 201 - 300 is OPTION 2, range between 301 - 400 is OPTION 3. These numbers are just example.